# No indication of any Error ( from javascript,timeout) IN IE 11/google chrome is not shown

Tags: internet-explorer, timeout, internet-explorer-11

as mentioned in the title, i would like to ask that why no error is shown in my IE or google chrome ?

I have my own application that is tested in IE 11 and google chrome. I try to make the program to be error on purpose (Object not reference, object is null, timed out, etc). However, my screen in IE 11 or google chrome does not indicate the error? Whereas, it should display at the below left corner of the screen, right? The application works correctly. I just concern more on no indication of the error. Any one knows of this?

Appreciate a lot of your answer guys :)

Thanks before

Comment: How about taking a look at the console, hit F12 ...

Comment: Hi Teemu, thank you for the response. if i press F12, the error i can see. However, there still is no indicator at the left corner below of the screen.  What should i see perhaps from debugging the console ?

Comment: Hmm... I haven't seen the "error indicator" since IE7, maybe it doesn't even exist in all modern browsers.

Comment: Allright, nevermind dude. Btw I wanna ask different thing, can i ? I just wonder that why all values in viewstate are being reset if only there is timed out? Let's say on the page load i assign one variable with false. on submit, i assign that to be true, then timeout happens, after refresh, the value becomes false instead of true. Do you know why?

Comment: Please post a new question with relevant code.